# How to get key and value from text file and set value in combobox

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox, key

I have two Combobox in my window form application.1st Combobox show the city name of country which I already got from database from xls file. the Combobox shows city name like this -

```
     Berlin
     Munich 
     Stuttgart //etc.
```

Now I wrote a text file which contain point of interest list of that places. my textfile look like

```
Berlin,Berlin Wall,Brandenburg Gate,Reichstag Building
Munich,Nymphenburg palace,Museum Island,Marienplatz
Stuttgart,Old Castle,Staatsgalerie Stuttgart,schlossplatz stuttgart //etc
```

Now I want that when one place appear in first combobox, all the POI Item will be generated automatically in 2nd combobox in a list form like when I click Berlin 2nd combobox will show

```
  Berlin Wall
  Brandenburg Gate
  Reichstag Building
```

But I am not sure how to proceed for doing this.

My code is-

ComboBox 1 filled in follwing way

```
 class PlaceList
   {
      public static ComboBox Combo_list = new ComboBox();
      public static DataGridView dataTable = new DataGridView();

      public static void List()
      {

        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        string SavedfileName = "POI_list.json";
        var Saving_path = Path.Combine(folderName, SavedfileName);

        string fileName = "Zensus_Gemeinden_org.xlsx";
        var path = Path.Combine(startPath, fileName);

        String name = "Gemeinden_31.12.2011_Vergleich";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                       path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select [3] as City,[4] as Population, * From [" + name + "$D7:E11300] Where [4] > 10000", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(data);
        dataTable.DataSource = data;



        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Combo_list.Items.Add(data.Rows[i]["City"]);
        }
        string Place_Json = "Place_List:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(Saving_path, Place_Json);

       }
    }
  }
```

Then I call it from From1.cs Like thís

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        PlaceList.Combo_list = comboBox1;


    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to load your file and line by line build an entry in a dictionary where the key is the string with the city name and the value is a list of strings with the POI. Then when you choose a city from the combo just use that string as the key to search your dictionary

Comment: Thank you But I am very new handling this problem, do you have any example for this. @Steve

Comment: Why did you copy part of the @Steve answer to the question?

Comment: @nickc of course you are new to this site and probably you don't realize that changing the question in this way makes difficult to evaluate correctly the answers. Please don't do that and if you have some kind of problem with the answer received feel free to comment on the answer asking for clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your file and line by line build an entry in a dictionary where the key is the string with the city name and the value is a list of strings with the POI. Then when you choose a city from the combo just use that string as the key to search your dictionary

For example, this is a full sample that you can test using [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net) and show how you could read your txt file and build a global variable that keeps your Point Of Interest keyed by city name

```
Form f;
ComboBox cboCities;
ComboBox cboPoi;
Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
void Main()
{
    f = new Form();
    cboCities = new ComboBox();
    cboCities.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cboCities.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Berlin", "Munich", "Stuttgart"});
    cboCities.SelectedIndexChanged += cboCities_SelectedIndexChanged;
    f.Controls.Add(cboCities);
    cboPoi = new ComboBox();
    cboPoi.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 30);
    f.Controls.Add(cboPoi);
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\temp\poi.txt"))
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>(parts.Skip(1)));
    }
    f.ShowDialog();
}
void cboCities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txt = cboCities.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (poi.ContainsKey(txt))
    {
        List<string> points = poi[txt];
        cboPoi.Items.Clear();
        cboPoi.Text = string.Empty;
        cboPoi.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi it is not working. I tried several times. Initially only 1 time it works after that it stop showing any value. @Steve

Comment: Strange, I have just tested with a simple app and works as expected. Can you put a breakpoint inside the event handler and check if the code is correctly called everytime you change the content of the cities combo?

Comment: Does your combo for the cities use a dropdownlist style?

Comment: yes. I got a long list from .xls file and it is dropdownlist style.

Comment: Then you should use SelectedItem instead of Text property but checking for null before

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more. Where should I use this.

Comment: in this line comboBox1.SelectedItem I changed but it show object cannot convert to string

Comment: How do you fill the cities combo? Using Items.Add or using a DataSource and a DataTable or DataSet? In this case did you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember property?

Comment: This is difficult to understand from here. I replace the answer with a full sample that you can try using LinqPAD (http://www.linqpad.net)  and compare with your own code.

Comment: I have modified my question in where you can get how I fill combobx 1

Comment: Did you call the List method of the PlaceList class? After or before setting the inner combobox to combobox1?

Comment: Hi in my code I do not need to put the city name statically. because I already got this from database. I updated my answer. @Steve

Comment: Yes. I set all value in another class. and then call from form 1.cs

Comment: Hi I modified my question.dis you see this because it still not working.@Steve

Comment: _Yes. I set all value in another class. and then call from form 1.cs_ please without proper information it is not possible to guess how your code flows. Where is this _other class_ ? How and when do you call the PlaceList.List method that initializes combobox1 through the static instance of Combo_list? Do you realize that if you call PlaceList.List method BEFORE setting the combobox1 you are effectively initializing a different combobox?

Comment: Place_list is separate class. In Form1.cs I call this.@Steve

Comment: May I know how do you call this class from form1.cs. @Steve . Or am I allowed to upload full code here, then may be you can understand.

Comment: your first code is working perfectly. I made a mistake that is why it was not working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is my Edited answer:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LoadKeys();

    }
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private void LoadKeys()
    {

       foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("TextFile1.txt"))
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());
                    poi[parts[0]] = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));
                }

    }

    void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string txt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (poi.ContainsKey(txt))
            {
                List<string> points = poi[txt];
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```